# Ruby File gets not reading content after last blank line \n

Tags: ruby, gets

I'm trying to write a very simple ruby script that opens a text file, removes the \n from the end of lines UNLESS the line starts with a non-alphabetic character OR the line itself is blank (\n).

The code below works fine, except that it skips all of the content beyond the last \n line.  When I add \n\n to the end of the file, it works perfectly.  Examples:  A file with this text in it works great and pulls everything to one line:

```
Hello
there my
friend how are you?
```

becomes `Hello there my friend how are you?`

But text like this:

```
Hello

there

my friend
how
are you today
```

returns just `Hello` and `There`, and completely skips the last 3 lines.  If I add 2 blank lines to the end, it will pick up everything and behave as I want it to.

Can anybody explain to me why this happens?  Obviously I know I can fix this instance by appending `\n\n` to the end of the source file at the start, but that doesn't help me understand why the `.gets` isn't working as I'd expect.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
source_file_name = "somefile.txt"
destination_file_name = "some_other_file.txt"
source_file = File.new(source_file_name, "r")

para = []
x = ""
while (line = source_file.gets)
  if line != "\n"
    if line[0].match(/[A-z]/)   #If the first character is a letter
        x += line.chomp + " "
    else
      x += "\n" + line.chomp + " "
    end
  else
    para[para.length] = x
    x = ""
  end
end

source_file.close

fixed_file = File.open(destination_file_name, "w")
para.each do |paragraph|
  fixed_file << "#{paragraph}\n\n"
end
fixed_file.close
```

Comment: A blank line is "" not "\n". Also /[A-z]/ might not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact you only add your string x to the para array if and only if you encounter an empty line ('\n'). Since your second example does not contain the empty line at the end, the final contents of x are never added to the para array.

The easy way to fix this without changing any of your code, is add the following lines after closing your while loop:

```
if(x != "")
    para.push(x)
end
```

I would prefer to add the strings to my array right away rather then appending them onto x until you hit an empty line, but this should work with your solution.

Also,

```
para.push(x)
para << x
```

both read much nicer and look more straightforward than

```
para[para.length] = x
```

That one threw me off for a second, since in non-dynamic languages, that would give you an error. I advise using one of those instead, simply because it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is like a c code to me, **ruby way** should be this, which substitutes your above 100 lines.

```
File.write "dest.txt", File.read("src.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use a multiline regex. Maybe:

```
source_file.read.gsub(/(?<!\n)\n([a-z])/im, ' \\1')
```